# Missing a 'Nice Answer' while having 10 upvotes

Tags: support, badges, nice-answer

I did receive 17 upvotes for my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587207/c-why-put-void-in-params/5587262#5587262). I however [havent received](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=220988) the 'Nice answer' badge for this question. It's already a couple days old, so data should've been processed by SO already. Any idea why I didn't get the badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got a Nice Answer badge for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895185/how-to-ssh-from-within-a-bash-script/1895195#1895195) which, as of me posting this, only has a score of 9. I don't see any downvotes for that answer though, so I suspect someone upvoted it, got you the badge, then revoked their upvote while they still could.

The number of Nice Answer badges tallies with the number of 10+-scoring answers you have in total, but since they don't take away badges for answers that no longer satisfy the condition, they make up for that by not awarding for the next answer that's supposed to get you it. So six badges correspond to six 10+-scoring answers. The same applies for answers to questions which have since been deleted, or answers which themselves have since been deleted.

Comment: I gave him an extra upvote, so  he get his badge now, 9 votes it the worse number after 0 :)

Comment: @Ivo What about 24 and 99?

Comment: I now count 7 questions with more than or exactly 10 upvoted - badge hasn't been awarded yet. Will wait for that and accept your answer then. Oh and thanks Ivo :)

Comment: @halfdan When I look at your profile, I can see that you have 7 nice answer badges.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, yep, received it right after I posted the comment, accepted the answer (+1). Thanks guys.